# How to switch windows of the application in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, shortcut-keys, gnome-shell, window, application-switcher

How do I switch between windows of the same application in GNOME in Ubuntu 18.04? For example, if you have two Nautilus windows open, <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> will go to the next application (say, browser), but not to the second window of Nautilus.

Comment: Oh yes. I am sorry. I didn't look at every answer in that question.

Answer (score 0):

We can use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd> (usually the button with tilde symbol, the one between <kbd>Tab</kbd> and <kbd>Esc</kbd>) to switch between the windows of the same type. Additionally, to switch between tabs in the same window, we can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Pg Up</kbd>/<kbd>Pg Dn</kbd> depending on the application.